# 'grp' not declared in this scope,

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

I'm attempting to ensure a user is in the correct group before proceeding operations. For some reason, it's providing a strange compile time error.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>

bool getGroup() {
    const std::string group = "Controller";

    group *grp = getgrnam(group.c_str());
    if (grp == NULL) {
        ERROR("No group (%s) exists", group.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    std::string uid(pw->pw_name);

    for (char **member = grp->gr_mem; *member; member++) {
        if (uid.compare(*member) == 0) {
            DEBUG("Matched (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), group.c_str());
            return true;
        }
    }

    ERROR("Unable to match user (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), group.c_str());
    return false;
}
```

The compiler is complaining about `main.cpp`: In function

```
bool getGroup():
main.cpp:72: error: ‘grp’ was not declared in this scope
```

and this error corresponds to this line:

```
group *grp = getgrnam(group.c_str());
```

I've been reading the documentation about this in the `man` pages, and I believe I'm doing it correctly. Also, I can't see anything in my code that is incorrect. Maybe a fresh pair of eyes will help out.

Thanks!

Comment: @PavelAnossov You're exactly right. Damn I can't believe I missed that. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is a variable defined on the previous line, not a type. You are multiplying `group` with the undeclared `grp`.

```
    // define "group"
    const std::string group = "Controller";

    // multiply group with grp, assign to the result
    group * grp = getgrnam(group.c_str());
```

Fixed:

```
bool getGroup() {
    const std::string group_name = "Controller";

    // multiply group with grp, assign to the result
    group *grp = getgrnam(group_name.c_str());
    if (grp == NULL) {
        ERROR("No group (%s) exists", group_name.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    std::string uid(pw->pw_name);

    for (char **member = grp->gr_mem; *member; member++) {
        if (uid.compare(*member) == 0) {
            DEBUG("Matched (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), group_name.c_str());
            return true;
        }
    }

    ERROR("Unable to match user (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), group_name.c_str());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. I can't believe I made that mistake. Thanks for the help. I'll accept this in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
const std::string group = "Controller";

------------------^^^^^

group *grp = getgrnam(group.c_str());
^^^^^
```

You can't "hide" a type behind a variable and expect both of them to work.

I changed the first `group` to `groupname`, and it compiles fine like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <string>

#define ERROR(...)
#define DEBUG(...)

bool getGroup() {
    const std::string groupname = "Controller";

    group *grp = getgrnam(groupname.c_str());
    if (grp == NULL) {
        ERROR("No group (%s) exists", groupname.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    std::string uid(pw->pw_name);

    for (char **member = grp->gr_mem; *member; member++) {
        if (uid.compare(*member) == 0) {
            DEBUG("Matched (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), groupname.c_str());
            return true;
        }
    }

    ERROR("Unable to match user (%s) in group (%s)", uid.c_str(), groupname.c_str());
    return false;
}
```